# Wix doesn't insert var.publishDir into wxs file

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation, wix3.5

I'm using WiX tool to create an installer for my applcation

One step includes harvesting a directory in which I have all the program files. Here the command I use to harvest the files:

```
heat dir "C:\myDir" -dr INSTALLFOLDER -ke -srd -cg WebComponents -var var.publishDir -gg -out WebSiteContent.wxs
```

I get the WebSiteContent.wxs but unfortunately the `var.publishDir` get evaluated as "`C:\`" so I end up with a .wxs file which contains wrong file paths

Inside the .wxs file, I would expect the paths to be like the following:

```
$(var.publishDir).\relative\path\to\the\program\file
```

Instead, that's what I get:

```
C:\relative\path\to\the\program\file
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass it by defining DefineConstants in the Wixproj.

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <DefineConstants>
       $(DefineConstants);publishDir=$(publishDir)
   </DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
```